# Command for committing everything now and squash this commit to the last?

Tags: git

I often find myself doing this:

```
1. git commit -am '.'     # Message doesn't really matter 
2. git rebase - i HEAD^
3. <Squash the latest commit to the last>
```

Is there a one liner to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The one-liner you're looking for is `git commit --amend --no-edit`.

Make sure you do necessary `git add` first, or use `git commit -a` as you're already doing.

Comment: So then the one liner might be: `git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit`

Comment: @TTT If there is no new file to add to Git, `git commit --all --amend --no-edit` is enough - no need for two calls to `git`.

Comment: Yes, although I keep tripping over bad pre-commit hooks when using `git commit -a`, so I generally advise `git add -u` as a separate step instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of everything you're doing, reset soft back to before the most recent commit, and now add-and-commit. You have now replaced the existing most-recent-commit with a new most-recent-commit consisting of how things are *now*.

(However, I would suggest a different working method; just keep working, piling up commits, and don't clean up until much later.)

Comment: Although reset soft would work, I think amending would be slightly more efficient in that OP appears to want to reuse the existing commit message (though with a significant enough amend perhaps you ought to change the message). But I definitely agree with your second paragraph. Constantly amending makes it harder to undo just one specific change from a few hours back.

Comment: @TTT I think what I had in mind really is: what if we don't decide this until _two_ commits have been added, or _four_ commits have been added? This is the general squash strategy.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. .Not exactly what was asked, but *if* you have multiple commits to squash (which is what we both would propose), then this is more versatile. I also do this sometimes when I want my commit to have today's date instead of, say, last week.